# Boost library producing errors on ubuntu

Tags: c++, boost, installation, boost-asio

I'm trying to compile code I got from [here](http://www.gamedev.net/blog/950/entry-2249317-a-guide-to-getting-started-with-boostasio/?pg=1). I had installed the boost libraries on Ubuntu using sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev. The installation went fine and I was able to compile all the examples. Then I tried an [example found here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/03/20/boost-asio-with-protocol-buffers-code-sample/) using boost::asio and Google protocol buffers. Clang_complete in Vim started giving me some weird problems which lead me believe that I needed to update the version of boost. (Installed 1.46 from repositories).

I realized that the Ubuntu repository was using an older version of Boost so I decided to download and install it my self. I used [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1180792) tutorial to install the libraries (replacing ./bjam with ./b2). This is when the problem started. The code below worked fine from the Synaptic installation of boost but after the manual build I get lots of errors. I'm thinking something is missing but I'm not sure how I figure out what I need to install.

The code looks like this:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

boost::mutex global_stream_lock;

void WorkerThread( boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service > io_service )
{
global_stream_lock.lock();
std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()
    << "] Thread Start" << std::endl;
global_stream_lock.unlock();

io_service->run();

global_stream_lock.lock();
std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()
    << "] Thread Finish" << std::endl;
global_stream_lock.unlock();
}

size_t fib( size_t n )
{
if ( n <= 1 )
{
    return n;
}
boost::this_thread::sleep( 
    boost::posix_time::milliseconds( 1000 )
);
return fib( n - 1 ) + fib( n - 2);
}

void CalculateFib( size_t n )
{
global_stream_lock.lock();
std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()
    << "] Now calculating fib( " << n << " ) " << std::endl;
global_stream_lock.unlock();

size_t f = fib( n );

global_stream_lock.lock();
std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()
    << "] fib( " << n << " ) = " << f << std::endl;
global_stream_lock.unlock();
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service > io_service(
    new boost::asio::io_service
);
boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service::work > work(
    new boost::asio::io_service::work( *io_service )
);

global_stream_lock.lock();
std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()
    << "] The program will exit when all work has finished."
    << std::endl;
global_stream_lock.unlock();

boost::thread_group worker_threads;
for( int x = 0; x < 2; ++x )
{
    worker_threads.create_thread( 
        boost::bind( &WorkerThread, io_service )
    );
}

io_service->post( boost::bind( CalculateFib, 3 ) );
io_service->post( boost::bind( CalculateFib, 4 ) );
io_service->post( boost::bind( CalculateFib, 5 ) );

work.reset();

worker_threads.join_all();

return 0;
}
```

Now when I try to compile the code I get the following errors:

**Command Line:** g++ -o example3a example3a.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread
**Compiler Output:**

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp:24:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/units/detail/utility.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/exception/detail/type_info.hpp:19,
             from /usr/include/boost/exception/detail/object_hex_dump.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/exception/to_string_stub.hpp:16,
             from /usr/include/boost/exception/info.hpp:16,
             from /usr/include/boost/exception/detail/exception_ptr.hpp:20,
             from /usr/include/boost/exception_ptr.hpp:9,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:28,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:24,
             from example3a.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/formatter.hpp:102:16: error: ‘dissect_formatF’ in 
namespace ‘boost::algorithm::detail’ does not name a type
/usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/formatter.hpp:115:22: error:
‘boost::algorithm::dissect_formatter’ has not been declared
In file included from /usr/include/boost/exception/detail/exception_ptr.hpp:20:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/exception_ptr.hpp:9,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:28,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:24,
             from example3a.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/exception/info.hpp: In member function ‘virtual 
boost::shared_ptr<boost::exception_detail::error_info_base>
boost::exception_detail::error_info_container_impl::get(const
boost::exception_detail::type_info_&) const’:
/usr/include/boost/exception/info.hpp:100:21: error: no match for ‘operator*’ in
‘*boost::exception_detail::type_info_((*(const std::type_info*
(*((&p)->boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator* [with T =
boost::exception_detail::error_info_base, typename
boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type = boost::exception_detail::error_info_base&
().boost::exception_detail::error_info_base::_vptr.error_info_base
0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff8u)))).boost::exception_detail::type_info_::type_’
/usr/include/boost/exception/info.hpp:100:21: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:399:5: note: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp>
std::operator*(const _Tp&, const std::complex<_Tp>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:390:5: note: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp>
std::operator*(const std::complex<_Tp>&, const _Tp&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:381:5: note: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp>
std::operator*(const std::complex<_Tp>&, const std::complex<_Tp>&)
/usr/include/boost/exception/info.hpp:100:21: error: no match for ‘operator*’ in
‘*ti.boost::exception_detail::type_info_::type_’
/usr/include/boost/exception/info.hpp:100:21: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:399:5: note: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp>
std::operator*(const _Tp&, const std::complex<_Tp>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:390:5: note: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp>
std::operator*(const std::complex<_Tp>&, const _Tp&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:381:5: note: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp> 
std::operator*(const std::complex<_Tp>&, const std::complex<_Tp>&)
```

Comment: Did you *uninstall* the Boost from Synaptic?

Comment: FWIW that code compiles on VS2012. I downloaded and built the boost libraries myself.

Comment: Yeh, it worked for me too before I tried to upgrade boost. @DrewDormann I did a sudo apt-get --purge remove to get rid of the previous installation before I tried installing the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got it working. I was following the instructions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1180792) but the following seemed to mess up the installation:

```
/bootstrap.sh --exec-prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --includedir=/usr/include
```

(I noticed that the old version of boost was in /usr/include and /usr/lib. Thats why I added the options above.:(

Instead I simple tried this:

```
./bootstrap.sh
./b2
sudo ./b2 install
```

Now the example compiles.

Comment: It is a **very bad idea** to install add-on software in the path of package system.  As other comments suggested, you should have uninstalled libboost-all-dev first and then installed via ./bootstrap.sh into its defaults in /usr/local. The example would still work by those defaults.